# ¿Como obtener coordenadas en un hilo nuevo y pasarlas al mainActivity?

Tags: java, android

Tengo este código el cual consiste en un hilo nuevo aparte del hilo principal (eso creo), una vez abierto el hilo, busco obtener las coordenadas cada 5 minutos, el código corre sin bloquearse y sin errores cada 5 minutos (no se bloquea) pero no entrega las coordenadas, siempre se va por la Exception (lat = 999.999 y lon = 999.999)

Dos preguntas:

1.Cual es el error, como lo puedo corregir?

2.Cómo puedo presentar las coordenadas en dos campos TextView (@+id/latitud y @+id/longitud) en el mainActivity?

3.Cómo se puede cancelar o detener un hilo para que NO se ejecute mas?

Gracias

```
    public class nuevo_hilo extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private Thread workerThread = null;
    private Context thisContext=this;


    Location location;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    double latitude, longitude, lat, lon;

    public nuevo_hilo() {

        lat = 0.0;
        lon = 0.0;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        if(workerThread == null || !workerThread.isAlive()){
            workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){

                    for (int i = 1; i>=0; i++){

                        try{

                            Thread.sleep( 30000 );

                            if ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisContext,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                Toast.makeText(thisContext, "Permisson not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            try {

                                LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)thisContext.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

                                boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );

                                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 10, (LocationListener) thisContext);
                                    Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                                    lat = l.getLatitude();
                                    lon = l.getLongitude();
                                }

                            }catch (Exception e){

                                lat = 999.999;
                                lon = 999.999;

                            }


                        }catch (Exception e){

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                }
            });
            workerThread.start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
      }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

El mensaje de error de la linea **at nuevo_hilo$1.run(nuevo_hilo.java:90)**, corresponde a la linea **lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 10, (LocationListener) thisContext);**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Atrapar una excepción y no debuggarla no suele servir de mucho, de hecho, lo que hace es hacer imposible el saber qué está pasando. Te recomiendo que jamás atrapes una `Exception` si no que uses una clase más ajustada al error que puedas obtener ahí. O al menos si atrapas un exception tal cual, IMPRIMELO a ver qué ha pasado! Además, incluye en tu pregunta el log de la excepción para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: @Benito-B gracias por responder, de ANDROID STUDIO muy poquito estoy aprendiendo, antes programaba en Ai2. No se que es debuggarla o el log.  Se que se va por la Exception por que a través de una notificicacion (que aprendi a hacer) me aparece en 999.999 la longitud y la latitud. ¿Como imprimo la exception?

Comment: No es cuestión de android studio, es java. En vez de imprimirla simplemente quita el try/catch y mira qué pone el log. Si no dejas que tu programa se rompa cuando tiene que romperse, cómo pretendes arreglarlo??

Comment: Ya quite el try/catch no pasa nada, no se bloquea, ni genera error. ¿el log donde lo puedo ver? Tenme un poquito de paciencia por favor, soy nueva en esto y lo único que conozco es Ai2 y el salto a ANDROID STUDIO es abismal. Gracias

Comment: Android Studio es un IDE, no un lenguaje de programación. El lenguaje que estás usando es Java. Para imprimir una excepción lo más fácil es usar `e.printStackTrace()`como haces abajo... pues en donde pones `lat = 999.999;` añade lo mismo y te debería salir por consola el error que te está dando.

Comment: Benito-B Tengo un problema, desde que instale AS en mi PC nunca me a funcionado el teléfono virtual para las pruebas, siempre me genera un error (Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD) al tratar de ejecutarlo, por eso no puedo ver los errores por consola. Yo genero el archivo APK, lo instalo en mi teléfono y hago las pruebas.

Comment: Aunque estés usando un dispositivo externo puedes controlarlo desde android studio.... Android Studio permite usar dispositivos físicos directamente, y te instala la apk en él automaticamente y todo como si fuese uno virtual propio de AS. Te recomiendo que mires algún tutorial para empezar a entender el funcionamiento de Android Studio, te ayudará a avanzar mucho más rápido en el futuro.

Comment: @Benito-B buenas tardes, después de 3 días por fin pude instalar el EMULADOR AVD, logre capturar el error y visualizarlo. Edite mi pregunta original para incluir la imagen del Log. ¿Es mas o menos lo que me decías que hiciera? Gracias

Comment: Alguien me puede colaborar y decirme por favor, cual es el error de mi código y como corregirlo. Gracias

Comment: Estás haciendo un hilo que va a tener que recibir datos de otro (En este caso los datos de la ubicación) sin haber llamado a Looper.prepare() tal como te está indicando el error. Intenta añadir esa llamada dentro del runnable a ver

Comment: Estuve leyendo la documentación para saber como implementar el Looper.prepare(), pero la verdad no lo entiendo, es muy complicado para mí, me podrías decir por favor como lo hago en mi caso @Benito-B

Answer (score 2):

> Cómo puedo presentar las coordenadas en dos campos TextView
> (@+id/latitud y @+id/longitud) en el mainActivity?

Simplemente agrega un mètodo a tu servicio para enviar los datos actualizados de latitud longitud:

```
public class nuevo_hilo extends Service implements LocationListener {

   ...
   ...

   public enviaInformacion() {
      Intent i = new Intent();
      i.putExtras("latitude", latitude);
      i.putExtras("longitude", longitude);

      sendBroadcast(i);
   }

 }
```

Implementa en tu Activity el recibir estos datos desde el servicio, asignarlos a tus respectivos TextView:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  double latitude, longitude;
   
   BroadcastReceiver breceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      public void onReceive(Intent i) {
         latitude = (double) i.getExtras().get("latitude");
         longitude = (double) i.getExtras().get("latitude");

         textViewLat.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
         textViewLong.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));


      }
    ...
    ...
}
```

> Cómo se puede cancelar o detener un hilo para que NO se ejecute mas?

Simplemente deten el servicio:

```
Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, nuevo_hilo.class);
stopService(myService);
```

Comment: Le hice un par de cambios y me funciono lo que me sugeriste, gracias. Una duda, putExtras y putExtra, ¿son lo mismo o son cosas diferentes? @Elenasys

Comment: putExtra (): se usa para almacenar cualquier tipo de datos primitivo directamente con el par (clave, valor), mentras que putExtras(): mantiene un objeto de la clase Bundle. La clase Bundle nos proporciona un método de métodos de tipo de datos primitivos específicos para almacenar datos en él. @Isabel

Comment: el putExtra es el que utilizo cuando uso SharedPreferences, es así?, el putExtras() es un poco mas complicado para mi, por lo que no lo tengo claro, debo estudiar como funciona, pensé que eran lo mismo, pero gracias por la aclaración.  Saludos